# Boot Error Debian: "ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)"

Tags: debian, boot

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this boot errors. I have looked all through the `dmesg`, `boot.log`, `kern.log`. I also have a  few `modprobe -b pci:<PCI ID> error`s during boot on the screen but I cannot find them in the logs. It takes about 5 minutes to boot.

DMI: BIOSTAR Group A75MH/A75MH, BIOS 4.6.4 04/17/2012

```
ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (INIT_DEV_PARAMS failed, err_mask=0x80)
ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)
ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
```

Comment: Does that machine normally have SATA II ( 3 Gbps ) or even SATA III ?

Comment: Did you recently install/upgrade Debian, or did you run it without these problems until now? Also, if possible switch of AHCI in the BIOS for the SATA drivers

Comment: It does have SATA 3 Gbps that is what I am using most. It is a new install of Debian Wheezy. I will look in the bios for the AHCI option. .

Comment: Ok so got into the bios and the options were Native IDE, Raid, ACHI, Disable. I switched it from IDE to ACHI and I got the same errors on boot. I also found this. http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3744228

Comment: That is not good, switching **off** could in some cases help get rid of the errors in the past (at the cost of some lost SATA commands, but not of performance).

Comment: AWESOME got it fixed bad HD. In the bios I looked at the drive configuration and one of the drives was registering 0.0 Gb but the drive is 500Gb. So I just unplugged it and rebooted no errors. I rebooted several times to make sure. No More Errors. Thanks! The one kinda odd thing is that the error states ata3 and the drive was on SATA port 1?

Comment: Last week I did not have any errors on boot. Now I am getting modprobe /b <pci id> errors again on screen. I am not sure where too look for them.

Comment: I tried 'less /var/log/* | grep modprobe' but I am not sure if that is the correct command or syntax.

Answer (score 3):

There seem to have been SATA incompatibilities around 2009 that caused the "ata3: softreset failed (device not ready)" problem, but nowadays I would rather suspect failing hardware to be the cause.

If you suspect a drive failure, and you use [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) control on your drives (normally a BIOS option), you can check the drive for errors in your BIOS, or once the system still comes up with:

```
smartctl -H /dev/sdX
```

(adapting `X` to the actual drive letter: `a`, `b`, ...)

A more complete status can be obtained with:

```
smartctl --attributes -H /dev/sdX
```

Comment: In the case of an old controller (particularly SB600/SB700 I think), this can be worked-around with `CONFIG_SATA_PMP=n`.

Answer (score 1):

AWESOME got it fixed bad HD. In the bios I looked at the drive configuration and one of the drives was registering 0.0 Gb but the drive is 500Gb. So I just unplugged it and rebooted no errors. I rebooted several times to make sure. No More Errors. Thanks! The one kinda odd thing is that the error states ata3 and the drive was on SATA port 1?